# SQL inner join, execution time

Tags: sql, sybase

I have this painstakingly slow query, and have no clue what the problem is. I have tried adding multiple where clauses but with no effect. Execution time is well over 5 minutes.

Goal is to select the last time that a product in LM_MAT is used. This is determined from the stock mutations; LMH_MAT. LMH_MAT does have 160K records, but doing a Select * from lmh_mat takes only 16 ms.

I have determined the solution to do so from [this site](http://blog.twinharbor.com/2010/11/16/sql-joins-that-limit-results-from-one-of-the-tables/).

Removing the second sub-query (select top 1...) does bring the execution time to just under 6 seconds, put removes the entire purpose: selecting the last time a product is used.

Platform: Sybase Advantage Data Architect.

I hope someone can help me!

Kind regards,
Lucas

The query:

```SQL
select
 lm_matn,
 LM_OMSCH,
 lm_hoev,
 lm_minh,
 lm_preh,
 lm_datin, 
 XDate
from lm_mat A
left join (select lmh_matn, lmh_id, cast(lmh_date as sql_date) as XDate
           from lmh_mat) F
           on A.lm_matn = F.lmh_matn 
           AND F.lmh_id in 
             (select top 1 FF.lmh_id 
              from lmh_mat FF 
              where FF.lmh_matn=A.lm_matn 
              order by FF.lmh_date desc)
group by 
  lm_matn,
  LM_OMSCH,
  lm_hoev,
  lm_minh, 
  lm_preh,
  lm_datin, 
  XDate
```

Comment: Can you post an execution plan?

Comment: Just to be clear you want to pick `lmh_date`, and `lmh_matn` from `lmh_mat` table to put into a left join with `lm_mat`?  If you were picking random values from the row this is very tricky, but both values you want are related to the sub-query, so there should be a simplification here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if something like this gives anything close to the result you want:

```
SELECT
  lm_matn, LM_OMSCH, lm_hoev, lm_minh, lm_preh, lm_datin, XDate
FROM lm_mat
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT
    lmh_matn,
    MAX(lmh_date) AS XDate
  FROM lmh_mat
  GROUP BY lmh_matn
) AS a ON lmh_matn = lm_matn
GROUP BY
  lm_matn, LM_OMSCH, lm_hoev, lm_minh, lm_preh, lm_datin, XDate
```

Comment: Yes, that does help! Thanks a lot!

What would be a solution to optimize this query if it were not simply max(lmh_date)?

Comment: @user2928360 In this case MAX(lmh_date) is the criteria you're using to find the record you want, so you'd merely be changing that criteria.  If you wanted to get something else from lmh_mat (like lmh_id) instead of XDate in the top part of SELECT, then it would get more interesting.  (I've done queries like that before but don't have any handy to look at)